# How to call limited number of data while making ajax call in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs

I am currently building an application using Extjs(I am new on this framework). In this framework I have followed MVC architecture. Currently I am working on an ajax calling to define a table grid which displays the records coming from Json File. in my json File I have more then 100 records and I am calling the file on my store which will be as following:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
 model: 'AM.model.User',
 pageSize: 15,
 proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api:{
        read: 'data/users.json',
        update: 'data/updateUsers.json', 
    },
        reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'users',
        successProperty: 'success'
    }
 },
  autoLoad: true,
```

});

and on my Viewport I have following PagingToolbar

```
bbar : Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
                    displayInfo : true,
                    store:'Users',
                    pageSize: 15,
                    displayMsg : '{0} - {1} of {2}',
                    emptyMsg : "No topics to display"
                })
```

Before creating the Toolbar i have displayed the grid as following: (it uses the Xtype as I have defined asss alias)

```
xtype : 'userlist',
```

As far as My understanding with Extjs this grid should display 15 records at a time and so on and so forth but this grid loads all the records of Json file all at once and gives the pagingtoolbar underneath it. If anyone could help me understand this It would be much more appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It is about Server-side problem.
your rest request will be like this.

```
http://your-host/XXXX-your-path/data/users.json?_dc=1380538796920&page=1&start=0&limit=15
```

It is a GET http method.
your server-side must handle it properly.
my code your can take a look ,i think it might be help.(it is a spring controller)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/user/user.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
    public LinkedHashMap<String, Object> listUsers(@RequestParam int page,@RequestParam int start,@RequestParam int limit) {
        Page pageItem = new Page(page,start,limit);
        List<User> plist = userDao.findAllByPage(pageItem);
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        result.put("success", true);
        if (plist != null) {
            result.put("count", pageItem.getTotalCount());
            result.put("data", plist);
        } else {
            result.put("count", 0);
            result.put("data", plist);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The important thing is handle Page Params properly.
My english is poor ,but i realy want to help you .